# Eloqua can we reprocess the data which is already in form submition data

Tags: eloqua

I want to resubmit the data which is already in form submission data on Eloqua forms. So that it can be rerun and added to the new CDO which was created after the form submission. Thank you!

The one way I know of is to export the data and upload to CDO which I do not want to as data is huge